# box-shadow color in Firefox

Tags: firefox, css

I am trying to fuse a block and its `box-shadow`.

The problem is: `box-shadow` start color in Firefox is not right. And it seems to be transparent a bit.

As a result I (and my customers) can see the border between the block and its shadow, which is ultimately undesirable in my case.

http://jsfiddle.net/v9Bzn/3/

```
<div class="white">
    <div class="black black-shadow"></div>
</div>
<div class="black">
    <div class="white white-shadow"></div>
</div>

.white {
    background: white;
}
.black {
    background: black;
}
.white-shadow{
    box-shadow: white 0 0 20px 30px;
}
.black-shadow{
    box-shadow: black 0 0 20px 30px;
}
```

### Firefox 25.0.1 (incorrect)

[image: Firefox]

### Chromium 31.0.1650.57 (235101) (correct)

[image: Chromium]

I can use `#fcfcfc` instead of `white` but the border appears in Chromium then.

What can I do to make `box-shadow` to be the same color as its `div`?

### Update

Yes, the problem is subtle. I can see 2 colors on this image (zoomed in incorrect image with color codes):

[image]

It is my monitor that makes issue more apparent for me. But there is no such issue in Chromium.

Looks like a minor bug but for some web page designs might be evident.

Comment: can't reproduce your bug

Comment: I can repro the issue on my system (OS X 10.8 + FF 25.0.1). I don't know if there's any easy fix apart from using some other method (images, SVG anyone :) ). Consider filing a bug report at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/ . This looks like an alpha blending issue (different method than in Chrome?).

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe, do you see the bug on images?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the problem in my browser but try replacing your classes with these

```
.white-shadow{
    -moz-box-shadow: white 0 0 20px 30px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: white 0 0 20px 30px;
     box-shadow: white 0 0 20px 30px;

}
.black-shadow{
    -moz-box-shadow: black 0 0 20px 30px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: black 0 0 20px 30px;
     box-shadow: black 0 0 20px 30px;

}
```

Comment: Those are good for compatibility. Interestingly newest FF (25.0.1) fails to work with these so you still need to have `box-shadow` declaration around. This doesn't resolve the actual issue, though.

Comment: @bebraw ty for pointing that out, edited my answer. btw like i said i cant reproduce his bug so i just told him to try adding -moz- just to see if it can resolve his issue

Comment: Yup. Maybe it's platform specific? I agree it's good to have those fallbacks in place. You never know how old browser your user is using.

Comment: Thanks for the try. If I had a problem with shadow visibility, this might be an answer. I am asking how to produce specific design effect with current Firefox and CSS3. IMHO there are some technical issues in Firefox `box-shadow` rendering that I need a workaround for. I can reproduce it on Linux and Windows. It is not platform specific for me.